# hashicorp consul DNS behind Traefik doesn't respond when using udp protocol

Tags: dns, udp, consul, traefik-ingress

i have my consul server (v1.9.1 deployed with official helm chart) running in a kubernetes cluster behind Traefik 2, i registered a client and now i want to get it's ip address using the dig command.

the problem here when i use the dig command with the tcp protocol it works but if use udp it's not

```
# Works
dig @<ip_address_traefik> -p 5053 <registered_node_name>.node.consul. +tcp

# Doesn't work
dig @<ip_address_traefik> -p 5053 <registered_node_name>.node.consul.
```

5053: is the port that i use for my dns traffic

Traefik listens on 5053/tcp (dns-tcp) and 5053/udp (dns-udp) entrypoints

ingressRouteTCP and ingressRouteUDP that i use to route my traffic to the consul-dns k8s service

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRouteTCP
metadata:
  name: consul-dns-tcp
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - dns-tcp
  routes:
    - match: HostSNI(`*`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: consul-dns
          port:  53
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRouteUDP
metadata:
  name: consul-dns-udp
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - dns-udp
  routes:
    - services:
        - name: consul-dns
          port:  53
```

if i ssh to the worker node where consul server is deployed and i use the ClusterIP of the consul-dns service (port 53) or even using the ip address of the consul server pod (port 8600), the dig command works using both protocols

other info

```
# kubectl get svc
consul-dns      ClusterIP   <clusterIP>    <none>        53/TCP,53/UDP                                                             
consul-server   ClusterIP   None           <none>        8500/TCP,8301/TCP,8301/UDP,8302/TCP,8302/UDP,8300/TCP,8600/TCP,8600/UDP


# kubectl get ep
consul-dns      <consul-server-podIP>:8600,<consul-server-podIP>:8600
```

any ideas ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Traefik's Helm chart exposes UDP listeners on a separate load balancer than TCP traffic. TCP traffic resides on the LoadBalancer service `traefik` while UDP traffic is bound to `traefik-udp`.

https://github.com/traefik/traefik-helm-chart/blob/f147e4c/traefik/templates/service.yaml#L66-L111

Depending on your configuration, this UDP load balancer could be on a different IP. Check the output of `kubectl get services` where you should see the IP address for this other load balancer service.

If you're using a load balancer provider such as [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/), its possible to configure the load balancer service for UDP traffic to use the same IP as TCP by adding the `metallb.universe.tf/allow-shared-ip` annotation to the list of Traefik's service annotations (see: MetalLB: [IP Address Sharing](https://metallb.universe.tf/usage/#ip-address-sharing)). For example:

```yaml
---
# traefik-values.yaml
service:
  annotations:
    metallb.universe.tf/allow-shared-ip: traefik-external-service
```

When you deploy the Helm chart, the `traefik` and `traefik-udp` load balancer services will utilize the same IP address.

```sh
$ kubectl -n traefik get services
NAME          TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                                     AGE
traefik       LoadBalancer   10.43.230.205   10.0.0.200    5053:31662/TCP,80:32021/TCP,443:31845/TCP   20m
traefik-udp   LoadBalancer   10.43.82.75     10.0.0.200    5053:30648/UDP                              20m
```

You should then be able to query Consul's DNS over both TCP and UDP protocols.

```sh
$ dig @10.0.0.200 -p 5053 consul.service.consul +short +tcp
10.0.0.132
10.0.0.37
10.0.0.82

$ dig @10.0.0.200 -p 5053 consul.service.consul +short
10.0.0.82
10.0.0.37
10.0.0.132
```